# DRF How to structure urls for photo sharing web app? (Structure/Best practice)

Tags: django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

Currently building backend API using Django Rest Framework for a group photo-sharing project.

I'm trying to understand what's the best way to structure my API endpoints and I've encountered a problem (more like a question) for the best way to implement it.

Here are my models:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    uploader = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="photos"
    )
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)
    upload_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)


class Collection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="created_collections"
    )
    members = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name="collections")
    photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photo, related_name="collections")
```

Basically each user can create a Collection model which holds different photos he can share with others and they can upload too.

The endpoints I have right now are the basic ViewSet ones:

Photo:

> /api/photo GET/POST
>
> /api/photo/id GET/DELETE/PATCH

Collection:

> /api/collection GET/POST
>
> /api/collection/id GET/DELETE/PATCH

**My question is:
What should be the endpoint for a user to add a photo to a collection? (the best way to implement it)**

**I've thought of a few options which are:**

1.POST request to /api/collection/id containing the ID of the photo I want to add.

2.POST request to /api/photo/id containing the ID of the collection I want to add the photo to.

3.Using a PATCH method maybe? (Don't know if that would be better)

I am trying to understand what would be the best REST practice in this case.

Let me know if you need to see more code,
Thanks!

Link to the git: https://github.com/davidplo4545/JustShare.git

Answer (score 1):

[This stackoverflow blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/) is a great explanation of REST best practices, specifically the section 'Use nouns instead of verbs in endpoint paths'.

Accordingly, your endpoints would look like this:

- GET `/api/photos/` to retrieve a list of photos
- POST `/api/photos/` to create a photo
- PUT `/api/photos/:id` to update a photo with the given ID
- DELETE `/api/photos/:id` to delete a photo with the given ID

This would be the same for collections, so to add an existing photo to a collection you would make a PUT request to `api/collections/:id` and update the photos field. The syntax of this request is up to your individual implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I will check the blog out. I pretty much understand what the approach should be but currently sending a PUT request to api/collections/id allows me to update the collection’s name and description. Should I write a different serializer for the same endpoint to add a new photo?